# html stylings to get 2 tables side by side in outlook mail?

Tags: css, mailchimp, outlook-2007

i tried below code.
code1:

```
 <table><tr>
    <td><table>table1</table></td>
    <td><table>table2</table></td>
    </table>
```

It works fine, But after certain height  introduces page break, which i want to avoid.So im trying below code,
Code2:

```
 <div style="width:650px">
    <table align="right" style="width:500px;">table1</table>
    <table align="left" style="width:125px;">table2</table>
    </div>
```

This is not working in outlook mail, Please can anybody suggest me How to make 2nd code work in outlook? or How to overcome pagebreak problem in first code?

Comment: The second example is actually incorrect HTML; could that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your content and space, you can use `floats` or inline `display`:

```
 <div style="width:650px">
  <table style="display:inline-block;">table1</table>
  <table style="float: left;">table2</table>
 </div>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SM769/1637/)

Comment: align="right"  and float: left;  stylings are not working for outlook mails, Is there any altenative option for it?